# Parsing json from array of array

Tags: ios, arrays, json

I have the `json` data were within the first array I main category array with name "Response" within that I have parent category array with name "0" within which I have child category array with name "0" and here is my `json` format

```
{"Response":[{"menuname":"Jewellery","menuid":"1","0":[{"catname":"Rings","catid":"1","0":[{"scatname":"Engagement Rings","scatid":"4"},{"scatname":"Wedding Rings","scatid":"5"},{"scatname":"kk","scatid":"35"}]},{"catname":"Pendants","catid":"2","0":[{"scatname":"Office Wear","scatid":"8"}]},{"catname":"Bracelets","catid":"3","0":[{"scatname":"Studded","scatid":"9"}]},{"catname":"Earrings","catid":"6","0":[{"scatname":"Ethnic Jhumkas","scatid":"7"}]},{"catname":"Chain's","catid":"33","0":[]},{"catname":"Jewel","catid":"34","0":[]}]},{"menuname":"Collections","menuid":"2","0":[{"catname":"SOUND OF LOVE","catid":"15","0":[{"scatname":"LOVE BRACELET","scatid":"16"}]},{"catname":"COLORFUL AFFAIR","catid":"17","0":[{"scatname":"Passion ring","scatid":"18"}]},{"catname":"Evermore Collection","catid":"19","0":[]},{"catname":"BOARDROOM GLAM ","catid":"20","0":[]},{"catname":"ETERNAL GOLD","catid":"21","0":[]},{"catname":"FASHIONISTA COLLECTION","catid":"22","0":[]}]},{"menuname":"Gold Coin","menuid":"3","0":[{"catname":"SOUND OF LOVE","catid":"15","0":[{"scatname":"LOVE BRACELET","scatid":"16"}]},{"catname":"COLORFUL AFFAIR","catid":"17","0":[{"scatname":"Passion ring","scatid":"18"}]},{"catname":"Evermore Collection","catid":"19","0":[]},{"catname":"BOARDROOM GLAM ","catid":"20","0":[]},{"catname":"ETERNAL GOLD","catid":"21","0":[]},{"catname":"FASHIONISTA COLLECTION","catid":"22","0":[]}]},{"menuname":"OFF THE SHELF","menuid":"4","0":[{"catname":"testing from pixel","catid":"13","0":[]},{"catname":"New pixel","catid":"23","0":[]},{"catname":"Evermore Collection","catid":"19","0":[]},{"catname":"BOARDROOM GLAM ","catid":"20","0":[]},{"catname":"ETERNAL GOLD","catid":"21","0":[]},{"catname":"FASHIONISTA COLLECTION","catid":"22","0":[]}]}]}
```

and I want to display in expandable tableview as below

```
Jewellery
  Rings
     Engagement Rings
     Wedding Rings
     kk
  Pendants
     Ofice Wear
Collections
  Sound Of  Love
     Love bracelet
  Colorful Affair
     Passion ring
```

Here is the code I used in `viewdidLoad`

```
 NSDictionary *pJson;
    NSMutableString *postStr = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kURL];
  [postStr appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?tag=%@&id=%@",kCategoryFilter,kPrecious]];

    [postStr setString:[postStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postStr]];
    NSLog(@"%@",postStr);
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:postStr];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    pJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",pJson);
    NSMutableArray *arr = [pJson objectForKey:@"Response"];
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)arr.count);
    NSMutableDictionary *dict2 =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];// [arr objectAtIndex:NSIndexPath.row];
   [dict2 setObject:arr forKey:@"dictionary1"];
   dict2 = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
   NSArray *arr1 =[dict2 objectForKey:@"0"];
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)arr1.count);
    NSUInteger y;
    for (int i=0;i<arr.count;i++) {
              NSString *ring_data = [[arr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"menuname"];
        NSString *id_data = [[arr objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"menuid"];
        NSLog(@"AUTHOR: %@",ring_data);
        NSLog(@"%@",id_data);
        dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      ring_data,@"menuname",id_data,@"menuId",nil];
        [myObject addObject:dictionary];
        NSMutableArray *arr1 = [dict2 objectForKey:@"0"];
        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)arr1.count);
        y = arr.count;
        for (NSUInteger i=0;i<arr1.count;i++) {
            NSArray *count = [[[arr1 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:arr]valueForKey:@"catname"];
            NSString *myCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[count count]];
            NSString *ring_data = [[arr1 objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"catname"];
            NSLog(@"AUTHOR: %@",ring_data);
            //  NSLog(@"%@",catname_data);
            dictionary1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          ring_data,@"catname",
                          nil];
            [myObject1 addObject:dictionary1];

        }      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some coding for you.Follow that code and customize where you want to add to array and where to set dictionary.

```
NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

NSArray *array=[jsonArray objectForKey:@"Response"];

for (int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSMutableArray *arrayDictValue = [dict valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",0]];
    NSString *strMenuName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayDictValue valueForKey:@"menuname"]];
    NSString *strMenuID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayDictValue valueForKey:@"menuid"]];
    NSLog(@"The strMenuName is-%@",strMenuName);
    NSLog(@"The strMenuID is-%@",strMenuID);
    for (int j=0; j<[arrayDictValue count]; i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dictInside = [arrayDictValue objectAtIndex:j];
        NSArray *arrayInsideDict = [dictInside valueForKey:@"0"];
        for (int k =0; k<[arrayInsideDict count]; i++)
        {

            NSString *strCatName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayInsideDict objectAtIndex:k ]valueForKey:@"catname"]];
            NSString *strCatID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayInsideDict objectAtIndex:k ]valueForKey:@"catid"]];
            NSLog(@"The strCateName is-%@",strCatName);
            NSLog(@"The strCatID is-%@",strCatID);
            NSMutableDictionary *dictInArray = [[arrayInsideDict objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"0"];
            NSString *strSCatName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictInArray valueForKey:@"scatname"]];
            NSString *strSCatID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictInArray valueForKey:@"scatid"]];
            NSLog(@"the strSCatName is - %@",strSCatName);
            NSLog(@"the strSCatID is - %@",strSCatID);

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: loop is infinite and strCatName is (null)

Comment: Have you checked very well?

Comment: First print the arrayDictValue after that dictInside,arrayInsideDict.Check clearly.If it does not have any object,tell me quickly.

Comment: Yeah they have objects.

Comment: Then where do not you have objects?

Comment: For strMenuName,strCatName,strSCatName were showing (null)

Comment: No not yet solved if I use this code I get log with infinite loop like this :2015-06-05 10:28:34.358 TAskOnExpandableTableView[801:15595] The strCateName is-(null)
2015-06-05 10:28:34.358 TAskOnExpandableTableView[801:15595] The strCateName is-(null)
2015-06-05 10:28:34.358 TAskOnExpandableTableView[801:15595] The strCateName is-(null)
2015-06-05 10:28:34.358 TAskOnExpandableTableView[801:15595] The strCateName is-(null)
2015-06-05 10:28:34.358 TAskOnExpandableTableView[801:15595] The strCateName is-(null)
2015-06-05 10:28:34.358 TAskOnExpandableTableView[801:15595] The strCateName is-(null)

Comment: You are getting response is not uniformly.If you have response,it must be same form.For example scatname,scatid is missing in 2nd and 3rd dictionary of array.

Comment: Go Google and enter online json viewer.Click that first link.Copy and paste the response in Text.Then click left side of the Viewer.It shows exact Json response and check it.Ask webservice team to form correct format.

Comment: Yeah thank you so much there is some corrections in code in for loop increment.

Comment: May you give the mark for me,If this  code useful for you?

Comment: Thank so much.If you need any help,please ask me.I help you.

Comment: Tell me.What do you want?I will help you.

Comment: Have a look on this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578895/button-in-tableview-footer-is-not-getting-called/31579043?noredirect=1#comment51119979_31579043

Comment: I need help in that issue dude

Comment: k no problem.i will fix.

Comment: pavithra i posted my answer please go through and check it.

Comment: Pavithra have you seen my coding?

Comment: Need another help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695820/tab-bar-with-slide-out-menu?noredirect=1#comment51336654_31695820

Comment: Yesterday I was on leave.Just now i got back to my work.

Comment: Okies take your own time .. Happy morning