# Button in tableview footer is not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have declared `UIView` and `UIButton` in the `UIView`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,300)];

    UILabel *totallabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,5,320,40)];
    totallabel.text = @"Grand Total =";
    totallabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Regular" size:10];
    totallabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    [footerView addSubview:totallabel];
    UILabel *lblRs = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,5,320,40)];
    lblRs.text = @"Rs.";
    lblRs.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Regular" size:10];
    lblRs.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    [footerView addSubview:lblRs];
    totalcostlabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190,5,320,40)];
    totalcostlabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Regular" size:10];
    totalcostlabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    [footerView addSubview:totalcostlabel];
    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    aButton.frame =  CGRectMake(70,50,150,40);
    aButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:119.0/225.0 green:49.0/255.0 blue:88.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [aButton setTitle:@"Checkout" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    aButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Regular" size:10];
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnChackOut:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [footerView addSubview:aButton ];

    [self.tblView setTableFooterView:footerView];
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return footerView;
}

- (void)btnChackOut:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"btn clicked");
}
```

When I click the Checkout button which is declared in my footer the click event is not performed and the action method is not getting called

Comment: just remove the delegate:

`- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return footerView;
}`

You already set the tableFooterView..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution and now it has worked.Apply the below code.

in .h

```
 #import "CustomCell.h" 

-(IBAction)actionContinue:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblViewCart;
```

in .m

```
@synthesize tblViewCart;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
   arrayImageCart = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ios7.jpg",@"iphone_6.jpg",nil];
   arrayPrice = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Rs 60,000",@"Rs 55,000",nil];
   arrayDescription = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Made In China",@"Headquarter is in US",nil];
   arrayOtherDetail = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Black Color",@"White Color",nil];
   arraySubTotal = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Rs 60,000",@"Rs 55,000",nil];
   arrayTotal = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"110000",nil];
   arrayTotalCharges = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"2000",nil];
   arrayYouPay = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"112000", nil];
   self.tblViewCart.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 }

// Button Action
-(IBAction)actionContinue:(id)sender
 {


 }

#pragma mark - UITableView Delegate Methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 203;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section==0)
       return arrayPrice.count;
    else
       return arrayYouPay.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Reuse"];
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    if(indexPath.section==0)
    {
      cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
      cell.imageViewCart.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayImageCart objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
      cell.lblPriceDetails.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayPrice objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
      cell.lblDescriptionAbtProduct.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
      cell.labelOtherDetails.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayOtherDetail objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
      cell.lblSubTotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arraySubTotal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   }
   else
   {
      cell = [nib objectAtIndex:1];
      cell.lblTotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayTotal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
      cell.lblTotalCharges.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayTotalCharges objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
      cell.lblYouPay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayYouPay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   }
   return cell;
}
```

Create Custom Cell through   NewFile->Source->CocoaTouchClass->Next>SubClassof:UITableViewCell,Class->CustomClass with CheckBox Also Create XIB file(This is for price details).
Then Inside CustomCell.xib file create another UITableViewCell and give name as CustomCell for Total Amount and Pay.

Answer (score 1):

Can't called because you don't set a height for footer, just need set footer height like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 300;
}
```

Comment: Now button is working but the footerView is floating.

Comment: @PavithraSelvaraj , or you can try remove method `- tableView:tableView viewForFooterInSection:section`

Comment: If i return 300 in heightForFooter more then half of my view is getting occupied whereas if I return 40 my view is perfect but button event is performed

Comment: try remove method `viewForFooterInSection:section` and  `heightForFooterInSection:section`

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 40;
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *footerView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 304, 40)];
    footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIButton *add_member=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    add_member.layer.borderWidth = 0.8;
    add_member.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    add_member.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    add_member.layer.borderColor =[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
    add_member.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    add_member.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
    add_member.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
    [add_member setTitle:@"Add Member" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    add_member.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:16];
    [add_member addTarget:self action:@selector(AddNewMember:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [add_member setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:140.0/255.0 green:198.0/255.0 blue:63.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//set the color this is may be different for iOS 7
    add_member.frame=CGRectMake(10, 5, 284, 30); //set some large width to ur title

    [footerView addSubview:add_member];
    return footerView;
}
#pragma mark - Add member

-(IBAction)AddNewMember:(id)sender
{
      //Some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the property for the button and the mention the property name inside action block like this.

```
-(IBAction)btn_check:(id)sender
{
   BOOL buttonstate;//default state is false.
    if(!buttonstate)
    {
      //Declare your action code here.
           //Use the button property name here for your action.
    }
   else
   {
      //Declare the button release code here ,its not mandatory.
   }
```